# The "Artful" Mysql module for newLisp does not connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, newlisp

I am trying out the Artful Mysql module with newLisp and the "smoke" test using the examples does not connect to MySQL.

Assumptions:

1. I am a newbie Lisp programmer.
2. Platform is MacOS X 10.9
3. newLisp 10.6
4. MySQL 5.5
5. The newLisp 10.6 standard distribution of the MySQL module works with MySQL 5.5, the Artful one does not.

> (module "mysql.lsp")
>   MAIN
>
> (setf db (Mysql))
>   (Mysql 4336914432)
>
> (:connect db "localhost" "RetransDjango" "pwd" "retransdjango")
>   ERR: list expected in function : : "localhost"
>   called from user defined function Mysql:connect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That module hasn't been updated to accommodate changes in newLISP syntax introduced in version 10.2. You probably need to use the `self` function...